# Coq's proof #Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I try to solve this proof but I don't find how to it.
I have two subgoals but I don't even know if it's correct.

Here the lemma that I trid to solve with this but I'm stuck :

2 subgoals

a, b : Nat

H : Equal (leB a b) True

______________________________________(1/2)

Equal match b with

| Z => False

| S m' => leB a m'

end (leB a b) / Equal (leB b (S a)) (leB a b)

______________________________________(2/2)

Equal (leB (S a) b) True / Equal (leB b (S a)) True

```
Inductive Bool : Type :=
          True : Bool | False : Bool.

Definition Not(b : Bool) : Bool :=
          Bool_rect (fun a => Bool)
                     False
                     True
                     b.



Lemma classic : forall b : Bool, Equal b (Not (Not b)).
Proof.
intro.
induction b.
simpl.
apply refl.
simpl.
apply refl.
Qed.

Definition Equal(T : Type)(x y : T) : Prop :=
           forall P : T -> Prop, (P x) -> (P y).

Arguments Equal[T].
(* Avec certaines versions Arguments Equal[T] *)

Lemma refl : forall T : Type, forall x : T, Equal x x.
Proof.
intros.
unfold Equal.
intros.
assumption.
Qed.

Fixpoint leB n m : Bool :=
  match n, m with
    | Z, _ => True
    | _, Z => False
    | S n', S m' => leB n' m'
  end.
```

Comment: Your question doesn't provide a definition to `Equal` or `Bool`. Also you need to tell us what you tried and why you are stuck if we are to help you.

Comment: @I edit my questions thanks. I'm stuck with 2 sub-goals and I don't know how to continue.

Comment: You're still not giving the definitions, and you're not explaining why you are stuck. How would you do it on paper and why doesn't it work for you in Coq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't introduce all variables in the beginning with `intros`.  You will get a too weak induction hypothesis. Just introduce `a`.

Then in each branch, consider the different cases of `b` with the `destruct` tactic.  It will simplify your goal and you can see if it is the left or the right side of goal that is true, and use your `refl` lemma to finish the goal.

The last case require that you use your induction hypothesis, and it is here that it is important that it holds for *all* `b`, not just one specific `b`.

Also, you didn't provide a definition for you `Nat` type, I guess it is something like this:

```
Inductive Nat := Z | S (n:Nat).
```

Here is a proof.

```
Lemma Linear : forall a b, (Equal (leB a b) True) \/ (Equal (leB b a) True). 
  Proof.
induction a. 
- intros b. destruct b; simpl.
    + left. apply refl. 
    + left. apply refl.
- intros b. destruct b; simpl.
  + right. apply refl.
  + destruct (IHa b) as [Hleft | Hright].
    ++ left. apply Hleft.
    ++ right. apply Hright.
Qed.
```

While it may not be as insightful, you can also use tactics that try these steps to get a shorter proof.

```
induction a; destruct b; firstorder.
```

will also prove your lemma.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I understand better now. I will try your advices to others lemma

Comment: Hello, it's me again. I just don't understand the meaning of "-" and "++". Have a nice day

Comment: They are just indentation "bullets" that show where a sub-proof starts and ends.  They are not needed, but makes the proof script more readable.  Its somewhat like brackets around code blocks in C or white space indentation in python, but they start with a "bullet", you can use both minus-signs, pluses or asterisks.  So for example, the first tactic `induction` creates two sub-goals.  With the - bullet you can easily see where the proof of the first goal starts and ends.  Destruct also creates two subgoals, marked with +.  etc.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Good evening :)